# Week of the current month - interval

Tags: sql, oracle, date

How can i select every 1./2./3./.4-5 week (interval) from the current months?

So not like:

```
select to_char(sysdate,'W') from dual
```

But i need an interval = week of the current month (for example 2.week of oktober, because it's october - sysdate). So, concretely:

```
select SUM(number)/((trunc(sysdate,'WW')/4) from my_table where date between ? and ?
```

Comment: Show some sample data and expected results.

Comment: So, i have a table where are sales data/columns. I have datecol, countcol, partnercol, idcol and so on..  upshot: i want average sale by weeks@current_month. So, i need an interval to select sum(countcol) @week1/2/3/4-5.

Comment: for example: i sold 5 piece of X in first_week_jan, 10 piece X in first_week_march, 15 pece of X  in  first_week_oct.. so i have sum(30).. and average is 10.. so probably, i'll sell at least 10 peice of X  in  next_first_week_month.

Comment: What is wrong with `to_char(...,'W')`? It returns the Week of month (1-5) where week 1 starts on the first day of the month and ends on the seventh.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I need the week of the months as where condition (interval).

Comment: @Georgy : That's not how you show sample data and expected results ( through comments )   Edit your question https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53044468/edit and add some rows for sample data and for expected output in tabular format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(datecol,'W') AS week, 
       SUM(countcol) AS sum_of_sales
FROM sales
  WHERE TO_CHAR(datecol,'YYYYMM') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMM') --current year and month.
  GROUP BY TO_CHAR(datecol,'W')
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(datecol,'W')
```

Comment: It was helpful, 'cuz i used TO_CHAR(datecol,'YYYYW') to select weeks... but 1 more question.. how can I use: to_char(datecol, 'YYYYW') but previous year.. so for example: 20172. -1 is not good, because it's changing the current week..